# SQL Timestamp format in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, format

I little bit stuck in SQL datetime format, I'm using `datetime` format because of sorting reasons.

The issue come that MySQL expect date in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format and I need in exactly the opposite `dd-mm-yyyy`. There is some way pass and get in different format using PHP? 
.

Comment: provide some code!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson This is even not close to my question...

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov isn't necessary. The guy bellow you answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this should help:

```
$datedb = "2018-03-01 11:54:33";
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($datedb));
echo $date; // will print 01-03-2018
```

And read about `date()` function of `php`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php; https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)**.it Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

```
$mydate = "27-12-2017";
$dbdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($mydate));
//OP 2017-12-27
```